# How to list file names without extension but keeping the spaces?

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to create a list of files (about 4000) with batch file but without the extensions, some of the file names have `-` or `_` or **spaces** which I would like to keep them the same, and then I am going to copy and paste the list inside Excel and run a macro that I found on this website to create individual files with different extension using the names on that list. I hope I make sense.

Here is my attempt so far:

```
for /f %%a in ('dir /b *.dsg') do @echo %%~na >txt1.txt
```

But this one just creates a list with only one name.

Comment: You need two ">" to append to a file.  One ">" overwrites a file.

Comment: Do  `(for /f %%a in ('dir /b *.dsg') do @echo %%~na) >txt1.txt`. If doesn't work either make sure there's more than one .dsg file in that folder.

Comment: [`for /F`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) uses spaces and tabs as default delimiters, so add the option string `"delims="`; see `for /?` for details...

Comment: Thank you -dsg  it worked .

Comment: I just noticed a problem, I have a file like this  "name-  lastname"  and the command did not read the "lastname" because there was a space after the dash..

Comment: I tried this but still does not read the text after the "undescore"       (for /f "delims=_" %%a  in ('dir /b *.*') do @echo %%~na) >txt1.txt

Comment: You can just use a normal FOR command. `for %%a in (*.dsg) do @echo %%~na >>txt1.txt`

Answer (score 1):

The batch code for this simple task is:

```
@echo off
del txt1.txt 2>nul
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir *.dsg /A-D /B 2^>nul') do echo %%~nI>>txt1.txt
```

The command **DEL** is used to delete a probably already existing file `txt1.txt` with redirecting the error message output to handle **STDERR** to device **NUL** to suppress it in case of the file does not exist in current directory.

Next the command **DIR** is executed by **FOR** in a separate command process. **DIR** lists only the names of all files matching the pattern `*.dsg` because of `/A-D` (not directory attribute) in bare format because of `/B`.

The error message output by **DIR** in case of no *.dsg file in current directory is suppressed by redirecting it to device **NUL**. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped here with caret character `^` to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter parses the **FOR** command line. Later on execution of **DIR** command line `>` is interpreted as redirection operator.

The list output by **DIR** is parsed by **FOR** line by line. The option `delims=` disables splitting up each line using spaces/tabs as delimiter. So assigned to loop variable `I` is always the entire line read from output of **DIR**.

Output by **ECHO** to handle **STDOUT** is the string left of last dot, i.e. the file name without file extension. This output is redirected to a file with appending the line to already existing file contents.

A space between `%%~nI` and redirection operator `>>` would be also output by **ECHO** and therefore also written as trailing space into the file.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `del /?`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx).

Comment: Thank you very Mofi,  Great work. one question , Are batch file  capable of creating files using the list of name with an extension of my choice or I have to use the Excel Macro I found?

Answer (score 0):

@user8033911, based upon your latest comment, there seems no reason why you cannot replace the file extension with another as part of the same process.

The code below entered directly in the Command prompt window should show you, it replaces, `.dsg` with `.new`.

```dos
For /F "EOL=/Delims=/" %A In ('Where/F .:*.dsg') Do @Echo %A to "%~dpnA.new"
```

If you still cannot understand just comment below explaining where you are having difficulty.

Comment: Thank you Compo, The thing is I want to create a decoy file with the same name.

Comment: Just an empty file, a shortcut/link or a direct copy with different extension?

Comment: an empty file with same name and different extension: Example:

Comment: Example: PEDRSO.MP3  needs to be PEDRO.MP4 but I need the PEDRO.MP4 to be a let's say a Word document or any other file format . Basically I need to create a decoy files

Comment: …and TBF that would be too broad a question and therefore outside of the scope of this one. _A new question should be raised for any further help beyond that which was initially asked and answered_.

Comment: Hi Mofi, the purpose for this is to have the actual Microsoft Word format with the same name so in the future additional information about the original file could be added on, Your code worked perfectly , Thank you again.